# Find text under caret position

Tags: c#, vb.net

I could find the caret position in any application but I need to know what text (word) is there at current caret position.

How can I get the text?

Comment: some code would be helpful

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could find the caret position in *any* application (at least not by any means other than maybe screencapping the screen, then OCRing)... most applications probably wouldn't have any interface to request that of, and for good reason. Are you talking about getting the caret position of a control in your own application that you control the code of?

Answer (score 2):

It is very hard to understand your question which seems mostly to be phrased as a statement.

*Assuming I understand your question try a methodology like this...*

```
Private Sub CheckPosition()
Dim char_pos As Long
Dim row As Long
Dim col As Long

char_pos = SendMessage(Text1.hwnd, EM_GETSEL, 0, 0)
char_pos = char_pos \ &H10000

row = SendMessage(Text1.hwnd, EM_LINEFROMCHAR, _
char_pos, 0) + 1
col = char_pos - SendMessage(Text1.hwnd, EM_LINEINDEX, _
-1, 0) + 1

lblPosition.Caption = "(" & Format$(row) & ", " & _
Format$(col) & ")"
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As _
Integer)
CheckPosition
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As _
Integer)
CheckPosition
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As _
Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
CheckPosition
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As _
Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
CheckPosition
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a WinForms application, and by caret position you mean Caret Position in a textbox. Then you could do some thing like this.

1. Attach event handlers to KeyUp and MouseUp events

2. Get the current textbox Text and the Caret Position

3. Pass this to a function that returns the word under that position

```
    private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetWordFromCaretPosition(textBox1.Text, textBox1.SelectionStart);
    }

    private void textBox1_MouseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetWordFromCaretPosition(textBox1.Text, textBox1.SelectionStart);
    }

    private string GetWordFromCaretPosition(string input, int position)
    {
        string word = string.Empty;
        //Yet to be implemented.
        return word;
    }
```

For WPF Textbox caret position is represented by `textBox1.CaretIndex`

For WPF RichTextBox see this thread : [WPF RichTextBox - get whole word at current caret position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934422/wpf-richtextbox-get-whole-word-at-current-caret-position)

For Windows Phone 7 caret position is represented by `textBox1.SelectionStart`. See this thread if your app is a Windows Phone app: [Selecting the tapped-on word on a single click in textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193027/selecting-the-tapped-on-word-on-a-single-click-in-textbox/6193785#6193785)